# Move to SO or Programers

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I can find it with a quick search; But:

But there must already be a question here on meta about moving off-topic posts to SO or Programmers.stackexchange.com ore automatic.

Like:

1. Off-Topic move to SO
2. Off-Topic move to Programmers
3. Off-Topic Incorrect Move put back to original site.

Answer (score 2):

Until we are out of beta, only the moderators can migrate posts.

Any question which is closed automatically has its migration cancelled.

Comment: When do we get out of Beta?

Comment: When I vote to close as off-topic I am given the option to say that it belongs on meta. Can't we just add these other two sites to that list?

Comment: @LokiAstari, I wish I could give you a more specific answer. They'll take us out of beta status when they feel we've got a self-sustaining community operating here.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, as moderators we don't have the ability to affect that list. We'd have to convince the programmers to change the code and that's unlikely. Feel free to flag questions which should be migrated. However, note that we've been asked to only migrate good questions. "Here is 100 lines of code that doesn't work, please fix it for me" shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: @WinstonEwert - I understand. Code that doesn't work shouldn't be migrated but rather flagged is OT with a link to the FAQ *not* because there's no option to send it to SO but because it's a poor question overall.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, actually you shouldn't flag the poor question, you should vote to close it. One of things we should have to get out of beta is for the community to be able to close such things without moderator intervention.

Comment: @WinstonEwert - I *do* vote to close it as off-topic and am presented with a list of sites where it would be a better fit, but Meta.CR is the only option on that list.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, yes. yes. But you mentioned flagging which is different from voting to close.

Comment: @WinstonEwert - Oops, so I did. :) Can we add SO.SE and Programmers.SE to that list, or must we exit beta before that's possible?

Comment: @DavidHarkness, we have to exit beta first.